# How can I implement it by Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

For example , I have a class like below:

```
public class SampleItem
{
    public string QCD { get; set; }
    public string CCD { get; set; }
    public string ITYPE { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have a list:

```
var lstTest = new List<SampleItem>() { 

    new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "A"} ,
    new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "A"} ,
    new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C3" , ITYPE = "A"} ,

    new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
    new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
};
```

I want to get 2 Groups like

Group 1 :

```
new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "A"} ,
new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "A"} ,
new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C3" , ITYPE = "A"} ,
```

Group 2 :

```
new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
```

So, I just need

```
lstTest.GroupBy (p=>new {p.QCD ,p.ITYPE});
```

But now, if My List's order is like the one below

```
var lstTest = new List<SampleItem>() { 

    new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
    new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "B"} ,

    new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "A"} ,
    new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "A"} ,
    new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C3" , ITYPE = "A"} ,

    new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
    new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
};
```

How can I get 3 Groups like

Group 1 :

```
new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
```

Group 2 :

```
new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "A"} ,
new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "A"} ,
new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C3" , ITYPE = "A"} ,
```

Group 3 :

```
new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
```

By `LINQ`?

Thank you kindly for any advice.

Comment: What you want, then, it to split whenever the value *changes*, rather than a full group - there is no inbuilt LINQ operation for that; you would have to write it manually. I'll take a stab in a moment...

Comment: Thank you for your comment , yes ,  I have implemented it by loop. But , actually this is just one piece of my codes . I want to find a more clearly way to solve this problem.  :)

Comment: In second case your Group 1 and Group 3 are same. For multiple  groups some thing should be different.

Comment: @V4Vendetta  yes , the sample as Group3 . this is just a sample , but it is available.

Comment: So something like grouping contiguous items, such an implementation might be an interesting addition to Cadenza https://github.com/cadenza/cadenza

Comment: @Amar Palsapure  Thank your . Yes , as you said . that is my question... :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `GroupAdjacent` operator, such as the   [one listed on Eric White's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/04/21/the-groupadjacent-extension-method.aspx), you can do:

```
var groupedItems = lstTest.GroupAdjacent(p => new { p.QCD, p.ITYPE });
```

Answer (score 4):

(now that I post, I see that a similar `GroupAdjacent` has been posted, but I'll leave this here as an alternative implementation of the same principal)

With a custom extension method, et voila:

```
static void Main() {
    var lstTest = new List<SampleItem>() { 
        new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
        new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "B"} ,

        new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "A"} ,
        new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "A"} ,
        new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C3" , ITYPE = "A"} ,

        new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C1" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
        new SampleItem(){ QCD = "Q1" ,  CCD = "C2" , ITYPE = "B"} ,
    };
    foreach(var group in lstTest.Split(x => new { x.QCD, x.ITYPE})) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", group[0].QCD, group[0].ITYPE);
        foreach(var item in group) {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", item.CCD);
        }
    }
}
public static IEnumerable<TSource[]> Split<TSource, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TValue> selector)
{
    var comparer = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
    using(var iter = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        if(iter.MoveNext()) {
            List<TSource> buffer = new List<TSource>();
            buffer.Add(iter.Current);
            TValue groupValue = selector(iter.Current);
            while(iter.MoveNext()) {
                var currentItem = iter.Current;
                var currentValue = selector(currentItem);
                if(!comparer.Equals(groupValue, currentValue)) {
                    var arr = buffer.ToArray();
                    buffer.Clear();
                    yield return arr;
                    groupValue = currentValue;
                }
                buffer.Add(currentItem);
            }
            yield return buffer.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another GroupAdjacent implementation:

```
// name your utility class how you want
public static class MyEnumerable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Cuts a sequence into groups according to a specified key selector function.
    /// Similar to GroupBy, but only groups adjacent items.
    /// Reduces a collection a,a,B,B,B,a,p,p,p,p to (a,a),(B,B,B),(a),(p,p,p,p).
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of source.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by keySelector.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">An <see cref="System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable"/> whose elements to group.</param>
    /// <param name="keySelector"> A function to extract the key for each element.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// An IEnumerable&lt;IGrouping&lt;TKey, TSource&gt;&gt; in C# or 
    /// IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of TKey, TSource)) in Visual Basic 
    /// where each <see cref="System.Linq.IGrouping"/> 2 object contains  a sequence of objects and a key.
    /// </returns>
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupAdjacentBy<TKey, TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        using (var en = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!en.MoveNext()) yield break;
            var key = keySelector(en.Current);
            var elements = new List<TSource> { en.Current };
            while (en.MoveNext())
            {
                var nextKey = keySelector(en.Current);
                if (!Equals(nextKey, key))
                {
                    yield return new Grouping<TKey, TSource>(key, elements);
                    key = nextKey;
                    elements = new List<TSource>();
                }
                elements.Add(en.Current);
            }
            yield return new Grouping<TKey, TSource>(key, elements);
        }
    }
```

this can also be used like

```
new[]{"one","seven","force","wow","bye"}.GroupAdjecent(s=>s.Length)
```

returning IGroupings containing

- 3: one
- 5: seven, force
- 3: wow, bye